# Remove data points from a Mathematica array based on certain conditions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an array of lines defined by par of points:

```
{{{340.754, 681.}, {361.889, 0.}}, {{760.286, 681.}, {775.156,0.}},
 {{398.028, 681.}, {420.73, 0.}}, {{0, 681.}, {239.46, 0.}},
 {{175.78, 681.}, {190.651, 0.}}}
```

I want to remove the lines where the first x point is equal to zero. Tried it something like this:

```
 For[i = Length[lines], i > 0, i--, 
 If [lines[[i]][[1]][[1]] = 0, Delete[lines, i], 0]]
```

... but it is not working. Help!

Comment: Try `DeleteCases[lines, {{0, a__}, s__}]`.

Comment: Oh, you have more errors, wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

```
mylist = {{{340.754, 681.}, {361.889, 0.}}, {{760.286, 681.}, {775.156,0.}},
 {{398.028, 681.}, {420.73, 0.}}, {{0, 681.}, {239.46, 0.}},
 {{175.78, 681.}, {190.651, 0.}}};
```

then

```
mylist /. {{0, _}, {_, _}} -> Sequence[]
```

returns

```
{{{340.754, 681.}, {361.889, 0.}}, {{760.286, 681.}, {775.156, 
   0.}}, {{398.028, 681.}, {420.73, 0.}}, {{175.78, 681.}, {190.651, 
   0.}}}
```

and if you want to overwrite the existing definition you can write

```
 mylist = mylist /. {{0, _}, {_, _}} -> Sequence[]
```

If you find yourself writing loops in Mathematica, especially for simple operations, you are almost certainly not using the language effectively. Try to forget as much C (or whatever imperative programming language you are most familiar with) as you possibly can.

Comment: Many thanks! Where should I look for in to the Help for this /. syntax?

Comment: Found it here:http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html

Answer (score 0):

`Delete` does not touch original argument. Mathematica is functional-style, so objects are mostly immutable. `Delete` returns modified list, hence you should do

```
lines=Delete[lines,i]
```

You also forgot that `=` is assigment, not comparison. So, use `==` to compare and your final code is

```
For[
 i = Length[lines], i > 0, i--,
 If[
  lines[[i]][[1]][[1]] == 0, lines = Delete[lines, i]
  ]
 ]
```